# How do I prevent audio from muting when I use dictation?

Tags: macos, audio, microphone, voice-dictation, zoom

I interview people on zoom and write notes on my thoughts as they speak. I type slowly and would like to dictate while they're talking (while my Zoom mic is muted). However, every time I begin dictating, Zoom audio cuts out, making this setup impossible.

- Input to M2 Mac mini is a Blue Yeti external mic connected via USB.
- Output audio through my AirPods Pro

So, audio input for both macOS  dictation and Zoom is through the Yeti Mic.

How do I prevent macOS  from muting audio while I am dictating?

Comment: Look for the Audio MIDI Setup app (I think it’s in Utilities) and see if you can use the earbud’s built in mic to take the dictation, yet keep the Yeti muted without interfering with Zoom.